Puppeteer and Chrome: change browser language without restart
I'm looking for a reliable way to set and dynamically change the browser language with Puppeteer for Chrome. Currently, I set the language as commandline argument when starting a chrome instance:
const locale = 'de';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: [...puppeteer.defaultArgs(), `--lang=${locale}`],
  defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
  executablePath: await chromium.executablePath(),
  headless: chromium.headless,
  ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
});

Additionally, I set the Accept-Language header on the page:
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
  'Accept-Language': locale,
});

However, I want to re-use the browser instance for multiple requests with different languages, therefore I'm looking for a reliable way to change the browser language without launching a new instance.
I came across the Network.setUserAgentOverride from Chrome DevTools Protocol which also allows to set the language:
const cdpSession = await page.createCDPSession();
cdpSession.send('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {
  userAgent: await browser.userAgent(),
  acceptLanguage: locale,
});

I would like to know, preferably from an official source, if the CDP command is simply a low-level function for the high-level page.setExtraHTTPHeaders() function, and therefore only affect the HTTP headers.
Finally, there are similar questions but they are old and don't really have a definite answer or some answer only work for certain operating systems:

How to specify browser language in Puppeteer
Change locale on the fly after browser initialization with puppeteer


I have implemented a test suite to check all available options to set the language. You can clone the repository and run it locally to test it: https://github.com/zirkelc/puppeteer-language-experiment
Here is a summary:
The language can be set and retrieved in three different ways. On the client side, you have navigator.language (and navigator.languages) and Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale. The former seems to reflect the language of the browser, while the latter reflects the system language. On the server side, there is the HTTP header Accept-Language.
The best way to change the language (even without a restart) is to use this CDP command:
const cdpSession = await page.createCDPSession();
cdpSession.send('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {
  userAgent: await browser.userAgent(),
  acceptLanguage: locale,
});

This command will change the navigator.language (and navigator.languages) and Accept-Language HTTP headers. It has no effect on Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale. However, I assume that the last option is not used to determine the language on the client, so it is negligible. Also, you can use the navigator.language to create a new instance of Intl.DateTimeFormat as described by MDN so both values should match:
const formattedDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language).format(date);

I hope this helps!
